# How to fix ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous' when using Logistic Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am trying to use Logistic Regression to measure the following: Best Parameters, Best Cross-Validation Score, and Test score. I am using this dataset https://www.kaggle.com/ashaheedq/video-games-sales-2019 and have imported it in my code. The code is done in Python and uses Pycharm as the IDE.

I have tried looking at other tutorials on Logistic Regression, and have also tried importing the modules for Logistic Regression in addition to using the GridSearch function. Upon running the following code below I expected it to print out the parameters, cross validation score and test score but instead I got this: ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'

```
#examine dataset from april 12, 2019

import inline as inline
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import norm, skew

import warnings


def ignore_warn(*args, **kwargs):
    pass


warnings.warn = ignore_warn  # ignore annoying warning (from sklearn and seaborn)

data = pd.read_csv('../VideoGameSalesDemo2/vgsales-12-4-2019.csv')
data.head()
print(data.shape)

data = data.drop(data[(data['Critic_Score']>60) & (data['Global_Sales']>60)].index)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x = data['Critic_Score'], y = data['Global_Sales'])
plt.ylabel('Global_Sales', fontsize=13)
plt.xlabel('Critic_Score', fontsize=13)
plt.show()

data_na = (data.isnull().sum() / len(data)) * 100
data_na = data_na.drop(data_na[data_na == 0].index).sort_values(ascending=False)[:30]
missing_data = pd.DataFrame({'Missing Ratio' :data_na})
missing_data.head(23)

print(pd.value_counts(data["Platform"]))

data = data
[(data['Platform'] == 'PS3') | (data['Platform'] == 'PS4') | (data['Platform'] == 'X360')
 | (data['Platform'] == 'XOne') | (data['Platform'] == 'Wii') | (data['Platform'] == 'WiiU') | (data['Platform'] == 'PC')
 | (data['Platform'] == 'XBL')]

#Let's double check the value counts to be sure
print(pd.value_counts(data["Platform"]))

#Let's see the shape of the data again
print(data.shape)

#Lets see the missing ratios again
data_na = (data.isnull().sum() / len(data)) * 100
data_na = data_na.drop(data_na[data_na == 0].index).sort_values(ascending=False)[:30]
missing_data = pd.DataFrame({'Missing Ratio' :data_na})
missing_data.head(23)

data = data.dropna(subset=['Critic_Score'])
data = data.dropna(subset=['Global_Sales'])
#Let's see the shape of the data again
print(data.shape)

#Lets see the missing ratios again
data_na = (data.isnull().sum() / len(data)) * 100
data_na = data_na.drop(data_na[data_na == 0].index).sort_values(ascending=False)[:30]
missing_data = pd.DataFrame({'Missing Ratio' :data_na})
missing_data.head(23)

data['Publisher'] = data['Publisher'].fillna(data['Publisher'].mode()[0])
data['Developer'] = data['Developer'].fillna(data['Developer'].mode()[0])
data['ESRB_Rating'] = data['ESRB_Rating'].fillna(data['ESRB_Rating'].mode()[0])
data['Global_Sales'] = data['Global_Sales'].fillna(data['Global_Sales'].mode()[0])
data['User_Score'] = data['User_Score'].fillna(data['User_Score'].mode()[0])
data['Year'] = data['Year'].fillna(data['Year'].median())

#Lets see the missing ratios again
data_na = (data.isnull().sum() / len(data)) * 100
data_na = data_na.drop(data_na[data_na == 0].index).sort_values(ascending=False)[:30]
missing_data = pd.DataFrame({'Missing Ratio' :data_na})
missing_data.head(23)

print(data.shape) #pre-dummies shape
data = pd.get_dummies(data=data, columns=['Platform', 'Genre', 'ESRB_Rating'])
print(data.shape) #post-dummies shape
data.head #Check to verify that dummies are ok

data = data.drop(['Name', 'Publisher', 'Developer', 'NA_Sales', 'JP_Sales', 'Other_Sales'], axis=1)

print(data.columns) #easy to copy-paste the values to rearrange from here

X = data[['Year', 'Critic_Score',
       'User_Score', 'Platform_PC', 'Platform_PS3',
       'Platform_PS4', 'Platform_Wii', 'Platform_WiiU', 'Platform_X360',
       'Platform_XOne', 'Platform_XBL', 'Genre_Action', 'Genre_Adventure', 'Genre_Fighting',
       'Genre_Misc', 'Genre_Platform', 'Genre_Puzzle', 'Genre_Racing',
       'Genre_Role-Playing', 'Genre_Shooter', 'Genre_Simulation',
       'Genre_Sports', 'Genre_Strategy']]

Y = data[['Global_Sales']]

#Double checking the shape
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=42)

#Let's check the shape of the split data as a precaution
print("X_train shape: {}".format(X_train.shape))
print("Y_train shape: {}".format(Y_train.shape))

print("X_test shape: {}".format(X_test.shape))
print("Y_test shape: {}".format(Y_test.shape))

#We use the numpy fuction log1p which  applies log(1+x) to all elements of the column
Y_train = np.log1p(Y_train)
Y_test = np.log1p(Y_test)
#Check the new distribution
Y_log_transformed = np.log1p(data['Global_Sales']) #For comparison to earlier, here's the whole Y transformed
sns.distplot(Y_log_transformed , fit=norm);

# Get the fitted parameters used by the function
(mu, sigma) = norm.fit(Y_log_transformed)
print( '\n mu = {:.2f} and sigma = {:.2f}\n'.format(mu, sigma))

#Now plot the distribution
plt.legend(['Normal dist. ($\mu=$ {:.2f} and $\sigma=$ {:.2f} )'.format(mu, sigma)],
            loc='best')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Global_Sales distribution')

#Get also the QQ-plot
fig = plt.figure()
res = stats.probplot(Y_log_transformed, plot=plt)
plt.show()

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)

X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

#No grid to define for vanilla linear regression
param_grid_lr = [
    {}
]

#No grid to define for vanilla logistic regression
param_grid_logr = [
    {}
]

#Parameter grid for lasso
param_grid_lasso = [
    {'alpha': [10, 1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001], 'max_iter': [1000000, 100000, 10000, 1000]}
]

#Parameter grid for Ridge Regression
param_grid_rr = [
    {'alpha': [100, 10, 1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001]}
]

#Parameter grid for Support Vector Regressor
param_grid_svr = [
    {'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10], 'gamma': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1],
     'kernel': ['rbf']}
]

#Parameter grid for Random Forest
param_grid_rf = [
    {'n_estimators': [3, 10, 30, 50, 70], 'max_features': [2,4,6,8,10,12], 'max_depth': [2, 3, 5, 7, 9]}
]

#Parameter grid for Gradient Boosting Regressor
param_grid_gbr = [
    {'n_estimators': [200, 225, 250, 275], 'max_features': [6, 8, 10, 12], 'max_depth': [5, 7, 9]}
]

#Parameter grid for MLPRegressor.
#Current set of hyperparameters are the result of grid search that took forever.
param_grid_mlpr = [
    {'hidden_layer_sizes': [(10,5)], 'solver': ['lbfgs'], 'batch_size': [200],
     'learning_rate': ['adaptive'], 'max_iter': [800], 'verbose': [True],
     'nesterovs_momentum': [True], 'early_stopping': [True], 'validation_fraction': [0.12],
     'random_state': [100], 'alpha': [0.1], 'activation': ['logistic']}
]

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

grid_search_logr = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(), param_grid_logr, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=5)
grid_search_logr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print("Results from Linear Regression \n")
print("Best parameters: {}".format(grid_search_logr.best_params_))
logr_best_cross_val_score = (np.sqrt(-grid_search_logr.best_score_))
print("Best cross-validation score: {:.2f}".format(np.expm1(logr_best_cross_val_score)))
logr_score = np.sqrt(-grid_search_logr.score(X_test, Y_test))
print("Test set score: {:.2f} \n".format(np.expm1(logr_score)))

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

grid_search_lr = GridSearchCV(LinearRegression(), param_grid_lr, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=5)
grid_search_lr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print("Results from Linear Regression \n")
print("Best parameters: {}".format(grid_search_lr.best_params_))
lr_best_cross_val_score = (np.sqrt(-grid_search_lr.best_score_))
print("Best cross-validation score: {:.2f}".format(np.expm1(lr_best_cross_val_score)))
lr_score = np.sqrt(-grid_search_lr.score(X_test, Y_test))
print("Test set score: {:.2f} \n".format(np.expm1(lr_score)))

from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

grid_search_lasso = GridSearchCV(Lasso(), param_grid_lasso, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_search_lasso.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print("Results from Lasso \n")
print("Best parameters: {}".format(grid_search_lasso.best_params_))
lasso_best_cross_val_score = (np.sqrt(-grid_search_lasso.best_score_))
print("Best cross-validation score: {:.2f}".format(np.expm1(lasso_best_cross_val_score)))
lasso_score = np.sqrt(-grid_search_lasso.score(X_test, Y_test))
print("Test set score: {:.2f} \n".format(np.expm1(lasso_score)))

from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

grid_search_rr = GridSearchCV(Ridge(), param_grid_rr, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_search_rr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print("Results from Ridge Regression \n")
print("Best parameters: {}".format(grid_search_rr.best_params_))
rr_best_cross_val_score = (np.sqrt(-grid_search_rr.best_score_))
print("Best cross-validation score: {:.2f}".format(np.expm1(rr_best_cross_val_score)))
rr_score = np.sqrt(-grid_search_rr.score(X_test, Y_test))
print("Test set score: {:.2f} \n".format(np.expm1(rr_score)))

from sklearn.svm import SVR

grid_search_svr = GridSearchCV(SVR(), param_grid_svr, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_search_svr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print("Results from SVR \n")
print("Best parameters: {}".format(grid_search_svr.best_params_))
svr_best_cross_val_score = (np.sqrt(-grid_search_svr.best_score_))
print("Best cross-validation score: {:.2f}".format(np.expm1(svr_best_cross_val_score)))
svr_score = np.sqrt(-grid_search_svr.score(X_test, Y_test))
print("Test set score: {:.2f} \n".format(np.expm1(svr_score)))

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

grid_search_rf = GridSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor(), param_grid_rf, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_search_rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print("Results from RandomForestClassifier \n")
print("Best parameters: {}".format(grid_search_rf.best_params_))
rf_best_cross_val_score = (np.sqrt(-grid_search_rf.best_score_))
print("Best cross-validation score: {:.2f}".format(np.expm1(rf_best_cross_val_score)))
rf_score = np.sqrt(-grid_search_rf.score(X_test, Y_test))
print("Test set score: {:.2f} \n".format(np.expm1(rf_score)))

from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor

grid_search_gbr = GridSearchCV(GradientBoostingRegressor(), param_grid_gbr, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_search_gbr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print("Results from Gradient Boosting \n")
print("Best parameters: {}".format(grid_search_gbr.best_params_))
gbr_best_cross_val_score = (np.sqrt(-grid_search_gbr.best_score_))
print("Best cross-validation score: {:.2f}".format(np.expm1(gbr_best_cross_val_score)))
gbr_score = np.sqrt(-grid_search_gbr.score(X_test, Y_test))
print("Test set score: {:.2f} \n".format(np.expm1(gbr_score)))

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

grid_search_mlpr = GridSearchCV(MLPRegressor(), param_grid_mlpr, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_search_mlpr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print("Results from neural network \n")
print("Best parameters: {}".format(grid_search_mlpr.best_params_))
mlpr_best_cross_val_score = (np.sqrt(-grid_search_mlpr.best_score_))
print("Best cross-validation score: {:.2f}".format(np.expm1(mlpr_best_cross_val_score)))
mlpr_score = np.sqrt(-grid_search_mlpr.score(X_test, Y_test))
print("Test set score: {:.2f} \n".format(np.expm1(mlpr_score)))

# Plot feature importance
feature_importance = grid_search_gbr.best_estimator_.feature_importances_
# make importances relative to max importance
feature_importance = 100.0 * (feature_importance / feature_importance.max())
sorted_idx = np.argsort(feature_importance)
pos = np.arange(sorted_idx.shape[0]) + .5
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.barh(pos, feature_importance[sorted_idx], align='center')
plt.yticks(pos, X_train.columns.values[sorted_idx]) #Not 100 % sure the feature names match the importances correctly...
plt.xlabel('Relative Importance')
plt.title('Variable Importance')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to predict a label with a continuous output. Logistic regression is for classification problems with binary or multiclass labels. Did you mean to use _linear_ regression?

Comment: I have already used Linear Regression in my code. I thought by using Logistic Regression it would allow for higher scores and a more realistic trend.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. A regression problem is a regression problem, a classification problem is a classification problem. If you want to use a classifier, you have to bin or binarize your outputs into discrete targets, so it's digestible for a classifer instead of a regressor.

Comment: How would I bin/binarize the outputs for a classifier?

Comment: That depends what you're trying to predict. Binary? "Did the game make more than $xxxx?" `[1 if i > xxxx else 0 for i in data[['Global_Sales']]]` Multilabel? "Was the game in the x percentile for sales?" `pd.qcut` + `sklearn labelencoder` It might be worth reading through the difference between classification and regression before you decide how you want to use it.

Comment: Thanks! Will do!